# Image in android Gridview moves off the screen

Tags: android, gridview

I am trying to get an image to appear next to some text in a Gridview. When the text is sufficiently short, seems to work fine, but if it's too long, rather than wrapping as I expect, it shoves the image off the screen.

Here is what the app looks like when I run it: 
[App Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shrpO.png)

I've tried all manner of tags to get this to behave as I want, but nothing seems to work. The layout file controlling this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="10dp">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:rowCount="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nameText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Restaurant"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/resultText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Result"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_happy"/>
        </GridLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to switch to RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you has`android:layout_width="wrap_content"` in both the TextView and the ImageView.

Change it for `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and add `android:layout_weight="1"` in both.